# What project management tool to use for a geographically distributed team?

Tags: project-management, trac, basecamp

Currently we are using [Trac](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftrac.edgewall.org%2F&ei=qwSkTOuKNM-jnQffg_mtDQ&usg=AFQjCNFj9e7EQBej7FOQLMErR3QOrAtShQ&sig2=Igh4Hi7NNhL7FoH8fn9alw).

Tickets are good for tracking tasks and related discussions.

However, I think it has the following disadvantages or limitations

1. Tickets creation is too complex for
   team members with non-tech
   background.
2. Every little modification of a ticket
   generates a mail to everyone in the cc list,
   which is rather annoying considering the amount
   of tickets.

Our team is getting geographically distributed, and project management tool
will be much more heavily used.

Maybe we should just try another tool, here are features we need most currently:

1. Priority task list with status like `todo`, `to be decided`, etc.
2. Process of every task item in the list can be tracked.
3. Daily digest is generated and mailed to everyone related to the project,
   including information like `finished tasks`, `new tasks`, `new discussions`, etc.

So, what's your recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok its been a long time since ive had to use a management tool but i forgot the name of the tool.
I do remember being able to select whether the task has been finished or not and so on and alerting users in the appropriate areas.
Because i dont remember the name of the tool we used i will just give you a list of the top 15.

Have a look its highly suggested.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/11/13/15-useful-project-management-tools/

This way you can choose the one that is most suitable for you.
It might take a little bit more longer to find the management tool you're after but as soon as you find it it will be worth it and it will do the trick. so have a look and enjoy.

Let me know if this helps
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I REMEMEBER THE APPLICATION
after having a look at the 15 tools, i remembered that the app we used was called BASECAMP.
It rocked it certainly helped get our task done a lot more faster and efficiently.
Hope it helps you as well. but still look through the list and see if you find something better.
Basecamp

Here's what basecamp is a bout. a quick introduction:
Basecamp is often considered to be the best project management and collaboration platform out there. Its features are impressive: to-do lists, file sharing, message boards, milestones, time tracking, project overviews and commenting.

The user interface is definitely one of the best out there, and because of its popularity, tons of other companies are making products that integrate with Basecamp, extending its capabilities.

**PK**

Answer (score 1):

I currently use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org)... I switched from Trac mainly because i wanted multiple project support. Redmine is very similar to Trac, but it supports multiple projects as well as some more Basecamp-like features. IMO it was also easier to customizer.

I've been using it for a little less than a year now and its been pretty easy to work this thus far.

Answer (score 0):

[Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/), [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/), [Go Plan](http://goplanapp.com/), [Lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/) are all pretty easy to get going and you can easily integrate with SVN og GIT.

You could set up the ones not offering repository solution to work with [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)

For very small projects to could check out licorize.com (team version).

Comment: I didn't try http://www.springloops.com/ but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Would definitely suggest a SaaS here. Make sure it's something accessible from the internet, from anywhere in the world.

WORKetc is a good example of this, as the product development team is even spread across all over the world and use the WORKetc software to get things done, when it comes to, the WORKetc software (lol).

Their software combines project management with CRM, and billing - so under one system you can manage all aspects of your business. It's awesome if you want to avoid integration issues, training your staff separate apps, huge fees, etc.